# mp4 video not playing on ios mobile or firefox, but work fine in chrome and safari

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, html5-video, mp4

The mp4 video is hosted on s3 and cloudfront, with the following media info. [Link here](https://d2hvcb0wqheu5h.cloudfront.net/tkfinder.mp4).

```
General
Complete name                            : tkfinder.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 14.9 MiB
Duration                                 : 41 s 867 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 2 990 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.76.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L5.2
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 41 s 867 ms
Bit rate                                 : 2 984 kb/s
Width                                    : 2 924 pixels
Height                                   : 1 672 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 60.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.010
Stream size                              : 14.9 MiB (100%)
Title                                    : Core Media Video
Writing library                          : x264 core 163
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=24 / lookahead_threads=4 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
Codec configuration box                  : avcC
```

**Problem**: mp4 video not playing on firefox or ios mobile, but work fine in chrome and safari.

[image: mp4 not playing on ios mobile]

Is any thing issues on format or encoding setting or on S3 setting?

Comment: Based on the information provided, the video appears to be properly encoded in the MPEG-4 format with the AVC codec. The video also has a high bit rate and resolution. The problem may be with the specific browser or device compatibility. It's possible that Firefox and iOS mobile devices do not support the specific codec or format used in the video. To resolve the issue, you can try re-encoding the video using a different codec or format that is more widely supported. Additionally, you can check your Cloudfront and S3 settings to ensure they are configured correctly to serve the video.

Comment: Please do not delete then ask the same question repeatedly.

Comment: @AnonCoward Please do not give useless comments, ignore it if you don't know.

Comment: My comment had a point: I had an answer I was working on, but when the question was deleted, so was my answer.  I'm not likely to continue helping under such circumstances.

Comment: plays fine for me, iOS 16.2 / iPad / Safari

Comment: @mavicll Not clear if _"...Not playing on iOS mobile"_ means with iPhone or with iPad exactly. They don't share all the same Safari features (some are disabled on iPhone).. Things you can try testing... **(1)** Use a lower resolution like 720p. Maybe een at 30 FPS. **(2)** Turn off (disable) those three **BT.709** output settings. **(3)** Try a different **Profile** like "Baseline" instead of the current "High" in the AVC output settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the FPS to 30 and the resolution to 720, and now it works on my iOS device but still not on Firefox. However I converted a webm version, which works on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I use FreeBSD 13.1  GhostBSD.org  Chromium works to play your videos.  Firefox does not.  It has to do with the capabilities of the FireFox Browser that it does not play MP

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay
Firefox blocks all media with sound from playing automatically, by default. If you want a website to automatically play media or make other changes to your autoplay settings, you can use one of the methods below.

You can google on this:
https://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+play+video+automatically&oq=firefox+play+v&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0i512l4j0i22i30l2j69i60.12086j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8